# Flask-login currentuser becomes anonymous after server restart

Tags: python, authentication, flask

I successfully completed my web app with Flask ad deployed it on my server. I use current_user in some of my methods and I need that information for some purposes. Lately I noticed a problem. There was already logged in pages and at that point I restarted flask server. Logged in pages were untouched during that. And current_user became anonymous in all open and previously logged in pages. To prevent that, I tried such:

```
@app.before_request
def make_session_permanent():
    session.permanent = True
```

But still the same problem What should I have done? At least I would like to force all client pages to go to login page after server restart.

Comment: Something else is going on here; restarting the server should not log people out. How do you store a user? Is it backed with an sqlalchemy model with some kind of persistent session (filesystem, redis etc etc)?

Comment: my users are stored in mongodb. But as far as I know, users are checked only when trying to login and if they are ok then login is executed and user data are not checked again. The rest is about session.I think.

Comment: Ok, well I also asked about your session storage

Comment: session storage is in responsible of flask-login and web browser I think.

Comment: And again, _how are you storing your sessions_? Are you using flask-session? I'm not asking about the point of sessions in general, I'm asking whether you have provision for session objects.

Comment: About session management I dont do anything. I dont use session storage specificly. I trusted flask-login about that.

Comment: Ok, in that case, I would suggest you use flask-session and, probably, store the session object in Mongo since you already have that set up. Even then, I'm not sure why it's logging people out since the session is client-side currently, but it's also for security to store the session on the server

Comment: I solved it. I was using a variable secret key. a constant one solved that.

Answer (score 2):

with `app.secret_key = os.urandom(12)`I was using a changing secret key. I did it so that `app.secret_key = 'sansal54'` and it was solved.